# Using PrintQueue Class in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005, system.printing

I want to use the PrintQueue Class to Manage the printers and print jobs.
I am having Visual Studio 2005, but PrintQueue is not supported in vs2005.
Is there any way to use this class in vc2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrintQueue it self does not support ANY version of VS because its a class!
you may mean that you have trouble [with using .net 3.0 in vs2005](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/c4e22eb4-3dbc-4613-b119-c6cfdb55ee8a/)

Comment: Yes but vs2005 have .Net 2.0. do i need to install .Net 3.0?

Comment: Yes ...
the [PrintQueue class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.printing.printqueue.aspx) supports just .net 3.0 and higher. I would recommend [VS2012 with .Net 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads)

Comment: Please mark my question as the correct answer to close this question